# On non-symmetric commuting matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Could there be symmetric matrix $M\in\Bbb K^{n\times n}$ in some field $\Bbb K$ for which there is a non-symmetric $X\in\Bbb K^{n\times n}$ such that we have $XM=MX\neq cX$ for any $c\in\Bbb K$ (since $0\in\Bbb K$ this avoids $M=0$ degeneracy as well in addition to $M=cI$ degeneracy)?

*Does $M$ have to be diagonal?*

What if we force $XM=MX$ to be symmetric as well?

Comment: $M = id_n$ works for the first question right? But I suppose this is not what you want.

Comment: @M.U. Yes I do not want this.

Comment: Originally, this question was asking: "Could there be a symmetric matrix $M$ and a nonsymmetric matrix $X$ such that $XM=MX$?" The OP keeps changing the problem, hence my downvote.

Comment: The OP should decide what he/she wants to ask, instead of changing the question every few minutes. (For the history of the problem, see the comment below my answer.)

Comment: No, $M$ does not have to be diagonal; see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you can take $M$ to be the identity matrix (or any multiple of the identity matrix, if you want $XM\neq X$).  More generally, you can take a direct sum of examples of this form (i.e., $M$ is a direct sum of different multiples of the identity and $X$ is a corresponding direct sum of matrices, at least one of which is not symmetric).  In fact, if $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, then up to a change of orthonormal basis, these are all the examples, since $X$ commutes with $M$ iff it preserves the eigenspace corresponding to each eigenvalue of $M$, i.e. iff when you decompose $M$ as a direct sum so that it is a multiple of the identity in each direct summand, $X$ also decomposes as a direct sum.

For the second question, if $MX=XM$ is symmetric and $M$ is symmetric and invertible, then $XM=MX=(MX)^T=X^TM^T=X^TM$, and multiplying by $M^{-1}$ we find that $X=X^T$ so $X$ is symmetric.

Comment: thank you for the post I want something non-trivial.

Comment: does it really work for first part?

Comment: So $M$ has to be diagonal? There cannot be a non-diagonal example right?

Comment: $M$ has to be diagonalizable if $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, since any symmetric matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ is diagonalizable.  It doesn't have to be diagonal; given any example where $M$ is not a multiple of the identity, you can just choose a different orthonormal basis so that $M$ is not diagonal.

Comment: Could you throw in a concrete $4\times 4$ example with non-diagonal $M$ and a non-trivial $X$?

Comment: Take $M=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ and $X=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, and then conjugate both of them by a random rotation.

Comment: That is right $OMO'=(OMO')'$ will be symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

To answer both questions: $M=0$, and $X$ is any non-symmetric matrix.

((Once the full rank condition was added:)) $M=I$ will take care of the first part.

Comment: I am looking for non-triviality not jokes.

Comment: You should been more precise in your original statement then.

Comment: You changed the question twice (at this point), and I answered what you posted. You have wasted my time as well, by not formulating the statement properly. I cannot read your mind to see what you intended. ((A minute later)): And you've changed it a third time.

Comment: I did not ask your time. you volunteered.

Comment: CarlHeckman @Turbo The arguing is wasting both of your times and escalating the conflict. Chill, guys.

Comment: No, but by posting it, you implicitly asked for my time to solve it.

Comment: You are wasting my time by making me read this

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was running through my mind after I logged off, and I have a substantial answer.

Suppose $M={\rm diag}(d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_n)$. The condition $XM=MX$ means $d_i X_{i,j} = d_j X_{i,j}$, for all "reasonable" values of $i,j$. This means either $d_i=d_j$, or $X_{i,j}=0$.

If $d_1,d_2,\ldots, d_n$ consists of $a_1$ copies of $r_1$ followed by $a_2$ copies of $r_2$, followed by etc. up to $a_k$ copies of $r_k$, where $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_k$ are distinct, then that means $X$ has the form: $X=\left[\matrix{X_1&0&\cdots&0\cr 0&X_2&\cdots&0\cr \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\cr 0&0&\cdots&X_k\cr}\right]$, where each $X_i$ is $a_i \times a_i$ and arbitrary otherwise (as long as $X$ is not symmetric, which is possible if there is at least one $i$ such that $a_i>1$).

To choose a non-diagonal $M$, find an arbitrary orthogonal matrix $P$ and let $X'=PXP^{-1}$ and $M'=PMP^{-1}$. (If $k=1$, this won't be possible, however.) Then $M'$ will be symmetric, and $X'$ will be asymmetric, and $X'M'=M'X'$. ($P^{-1}=P^\top$.)

It is also possible to make $M'$ a non-diagonal matrix. For example, if $M={\rm diag}(1,1,2)$, $X = \left[\matrix{a&b&0\cr c&d&0\cr 0&0&e\cr}\right]$ (with $b\not=c$), and $P=\left[\matrix{1&0&0\cr 0&3/5&4/5\cr 0&-4/5&3/5\cr}\right]$, then $M'=\left[\matrix{1&0&0\cr 0&41/25&12/25\cr 0&12/25&34/25\cr}\right]$.

Comment: One last thought: Since every symmetric matrix is diagonalizable via an orthogonal matrix $P$, this will produce all $M$ and a corresponding matrix $X$ (which can be nontrivial, unless the eigenvalues of $M$ are all the same, or unless they are all distinct; hence there are no nontrivial $2\times2$ examples).